# changing $rootScope inside angular ui-bootstrap modal controller

Tags: angularjs

I have problem trying to change $rootScope inside modal controller, The rootscope change but not immediately reflect in the view until i refresh page. 
here is my code:

```
.controller('LoginController',function($scope,$rootScope,$modalInstance){

$scope.close = function(){
$rootScope.authentication = true;
}
});
```

and the code to open modal in other controller:

```
    controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$modal){
    $scope.openLoginModal = function(){
     $scope.loginMdl=    $modal.open({
       templateUrl:'myview/myloginform.html',
       controller:'LoginController'
    });
   $scope.loginMdl.result.then(
     function(){},
     function(){}
  );
    }
    });
```

Finally, the simple HTML to open login modal;

```
<div ng-controller='myCtrl'>
<button ng-click='openLoginModal()'>Login </button>

    </div>
    <div>
<p ng-show='authentication'> USER HAS LOGGED IN</p>
</div>
```

as you can see, I have change the "authentication" var of $rootScope, but the change is not reflected immediately in the html view.
Could have some advise pls.

Comment: $rootScope.$apply() cause an error: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$rootScope.$apply();
```

to get the the change in rootscope applied you have to use the above code.

Comment: $rootScope.$apply() cause an error: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: inject it into the controller to use it  like this controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope,$modal){

Comment: yes, Did inject $rootScope in the controller but still not working. any idea ?

Comment: OK. nvm. I manage to get it done via service. Thank anyway for your answers.